# kendo grid nested columns view from nested json

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, datagrid, kendo-grid

I have the following table and JSON structure which I need to use for making kendo grid[image: as shown in figure there is a nested hierarchy in the columns and finally a table like grid.]

In kendo I tried with columns and data-source but the problem is that my columns are nested and which are further nested. For example there is multiple modules and each module has activities which havegrades. Please suggest what kendo feature I need to use to implement this. Also if you want to change json structure please recommend a better structure!

Following is the exact JSON.(You will need to beautify it!)

```
[
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Read and Begin Project",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 10,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 1.2,
        "YourGrade": 12,
        "UniqueActivityId": 149
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 163
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 2",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 151
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 1",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 162
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 1",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 164
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 2",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 150
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 3",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 148
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Diksha Goyal",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 7",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 155
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Read and Begin Project",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 10,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 1.2,
        "YourGrade": 12,
        "UniqueActivityId": 149
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 163
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 2",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 151
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 1",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 162
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 1",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 164
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 2",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 150
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 3",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 148
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Avinash Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 7",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 155
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Read and Begin Project",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 10,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 1.2,
        "YourGrade": 12,
        "UniqueActivityId": 149
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 163
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 2",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 151
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 1",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 162
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 1",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 164
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 2",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 150
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 3",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 148
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Nikhil Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 7",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 155
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Read and Begin Project",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 10,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 1.2,
        "YourGrade": 12,
        "UniqueActivityId": 149
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 163
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 2",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 151
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 1",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 162
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 1",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 164
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 2",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 150
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 3",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 148
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Martin garrix",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 7",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 155
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Read and Begin Project",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 10,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 1.2,
        "YourGrade": 12,
        "UniqueActivityId": 149
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 2",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 163
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 2",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 151
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Exercise 1",
        "Modules": "Module 3",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 162
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 1",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 164
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 2",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 150
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis 3",
        "Modules": "Module 4",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 148
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2759,
        "StudentName": "Rishikesh Kumar",
        "Activities": "Submit Analysis",
        "Modules": "Module 7",
        "Weightage": 0,
        "YourWeightedGrade": 0,
        "YourGrade": 0,
        "UniqueActivityId": 155
    }
]
```

Comment: Where's the code your have tried so far? This isn't a code writing service. Here is an example of a [grid hierarchy](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy). Give it a try and if you run into problems, update your question and be specific as to what the issue is. I would suggest making use of [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/epume) to provide a small example of what you are trying to achieve, this will make it easier to provide assistance.

Comment: I was finally able to get this done. Problem was that not only my json was deeply nested but also very dynamic i.e., number of columns was not fixed and neither was number of sub-columns. So I had to write a script that dynamically iterated over the json and created a final columns object that was assigned to the columns property in kendo-grid and the json as datasource. I had assumed that kendo grid would take care of dynamic json but it does not. Also there is no article or thread on internet that gives a solution to this.